# Regarding a command in ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, ubuntu-12.04

Recently I found a post stating this:

To check for unread messages in your Gmail Account, use this command:

```
curl -u GMAILUSER --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | \
perl -ne 'print "\t" if //; print "$2\n" if /<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/;'
```

But it does send me the info about the unread messages ? Is the command wrong ? Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Clearly, it looks like `GMAILUSER` needs to be defined first. Otherwise, how is the command going to return your unread messages?

Comment: Google did not allow it for security reasons

Comment: What do you mean by "Google did not allow it"? You need to post all errors / exceptions you are getting.